# Multidimensional Regression Network in Keras quickly trends to 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I had a basic keras network predicting one value and it worked fine. I tried adding support for predicting 4 values, but when I do that, the output instantly trends to 0. Right now, the network is the simplistic model just for testing.

The input for the network is an array of shape (90,) and the output should have 4 values. I tried having an output layer with 4 nodes as well, but that showed the same behavior of this one. I've also tried some various loss functions.

def runNN(training_data,training_labels,test_data,test_labels, model = None):

```
if model == None:

    inp = (Input(shape = (90,), name = 'input'))
    model = (Dense(units = 90, activation='relu'(inp)
    model = (Dropout(0.5))(model)
    model = (Dense(units = 180, activation='relu'))(model)
    model = (Dropout(0.5))(model)
    output1 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu', name = 'preretirement')(model)
    output2 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu',name = 'cola')(model)
    output3 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu',name = 'initialNC')(model)
    output4 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu',name = 'finalNC')(model)

    complete_model = Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [output1, output2, output3, output4])

    optimizer = Adam(lr = .0003)
    complete_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
complete_model.fit(training_data, {'preretirement' : training_labels[0],
    'cola' : training_labels[1],
     'initialNC' :  training_labels[2],
      'finalNC' : training_labels[3]},
     epochs = 10, batch_size = 128)
```

The output after 1 epoch, and anything afterwards, is [0,0,0,0] for each test point. It should be a 4 item list with values between 0 and 1 such as [.34,.56,.12,.87]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're doing a prediction task or function fitting task. Two suggestions might help you:

- `sigmoid` usually works better than `relu` in prediction task.
- Do not use activation function at the final output layer.

The code below is modified from yours and it works fine.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

dropout_rate = .5
activate_function = 'sigmoid'
num_iteration = 20

inp = Input(shape = (90,), name = 'input')
model = Dense(units = 90, activation=activate_function)(inp)
model = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(model)
model = Dense(units = 180, activation=activate_function)(model)
model = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(model)
output1 = Dense(units=1, name = 'preretirement')(model)
output2 = Dense(units=1, name = 'cola')(model)
output3 = Dense(units=1, name = 'initialNC')(model)
output4 = Dense(units=1, name = 'finalNC')(model)

# # Your original code
# output1 = Dense(units=1, activation = activate_function, name = 'preretirement')(model)
# output2 = Dense(units=1, activation = activate_function,name = 'cola')(model)
# output3 = Dense(units=1, activation = activate_function,name = 'initialNC')(model)
# output4 = Dense(units=1, activation = activate_function,name = 'finalNC')(model)

complete_model = Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [output1, output2, output3, output4])
optimizer = Adam(lr = .0003)
complete_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                       optimizer=optimizer,
                       metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

# generate data for training the model
import numpy as np
num_train = 4000 # the number of training instances

# a normal distribution with mean=2, variance=1
training_data = np.random.normal(2, 1, (num_train, 90))
training_labels = np.zeros(shape=(num_train, 4))
for i in range(num_train):
    tmp = np.sum(training_data[i, :])/90.0
    training_labels[i, :] = [tmp, np.sin(tmp), np.cos(tmp), tmp*tmp]
print(training_data.shape, training_labels.shape)

# generate data for testing the model
test_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 90)) # 10 test instances
test_labels = np.zeros(shape=(10, 4))
for i in range(10):
    tmp = np.sum(training_data[i, :])/90.0

    test_labels[i, :] = [tmp, np.sin(tmp), np.cos(tmp), tmp*tmp]
print(test_data.shape, test_labels.shape)

complete_model.fit(training_data, {'preretirement' : training_labels[:, 0],
                                   'cola' : training_labels[:, 1],
                                   'initialNC' :  training_labels[:, 2],
                                   'finalNC' : training_labels[:, 3]},
                   epochs = num_iteration, 
                   batch_size = 128)

results = complete_model.predict(test_data)
for i in range(10):
    print('true', test_labels[i])
    print('predicted', results[0][i, 0], results[1][i, 0], results[2][i, 0], results[3][i, 0])
    print('--------------------------')
```

The code produces

[image]